How to accept any http request with NestJS with fastify
Using latest version of NestJS with Fastify, I'd like controller handler to receive each and every HTTP request even if they are invalid or just plain wrong (this is for testing webhooks).
For example: GET with JPEG in body and content type set to text/plain should reach the handler.
Ideally, this would be a single endpoint, others should not be affected.
